# Mostrar o valor, e não o ID de um form

Tags: html, python, django

Estou fazendo um sistema usando Python e Django. Em certo momento, estou mostrando uma tabela com informações do banco de dados. Segue meu html:

```
<tbody>
    {% for oportunidade in all_oportunidades %}
    <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="{% url 'crm2:editaroportunidadeview' oportunidade.id %}">
    <td>{{oportunidade.id}}</td>
     <td>{{oportunidade.situacao}}</td>
     <td>{{oportunidade.cliente}}</td>
     <td>{{oportunidade.categoria|default_if_none:""}}</td>
     <td>{{oportunidade.data_abertura|default_if_none:""}}</td>
     <td>{{oportunidade.valor|default_if_none:""}}</td>
     {% endfor %}
     {%else%}
     {%endif%}
     </tbody>
```

Porém, na tabela, nos campos de `situacao` e `categoria` está sendo mostrado os IDS dos mesmos e não o seu conteúdo. Por exemplo, aparece assim na tabela;

```
ID | Cliente | Situação | Categoria
-----------------------------------
 1 | Marcos  |    2     |    1
```

Mas eu quero que apareça assim:

```
ID | Cliente | Situação | Categoria
-----------------------------------
 1 | Marcos  |Cancelado |  Venda
```

Em models.py, defini `situacao` assim:

```
SITUACAO_OPCOES = (
(u'0', u'Concluída com sucesso'),
(u'1', u'Cancelado'),
(u'2', u'Em andamento')
)

situacao = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SITUACAO_OPCOES, default=2)
```

`categoria` desse mesmo modo.

Como faço para exibir o valor, e não o `id`?

Comment: Só pra acrescentar uma informação inútil, não precisa fazer o `{% if all_oportunidades %}`. Pois uma lista vazia vai cruzar pelo `for` e não vai fazer nada mesmo. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices):

> *For each model field that has choices set, Django will add a method to retrieve the human-readable name for the field’s current value. See get_FOO_display() in the database API documentation.*

Isto é, para cada campo do modelo que possuir a opção `choices`, o Django criará um método que retornará o valor legível a humanos para o valor atual do campo, chamado `get_FOO_display()`, onde `FOO` será o nome do campo.

Portanto, basta você fazer:

```
oportunidade.get_situacao_display()
```